# Android Gradle build fails: Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:r18

Tags: android, maven, build, gradle, android-support-library

**EDIT:**

> **This issue seemed to disappear by its own somehow, possibly due to the new Gradle build system becoming more mature.**

I have two separate Android projects:

The 1st project is an Android Library using *'android-library'* plugin for Gradle, which depends on the **support-library-v4:r18**. Snippet from *dependencies* in *build.gradle*:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
```

The support library is fetched from *Android Support Repository* installed via *Android SDK Manager* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740139/gradle-and-android-support-library). This project is then built and published to maven local repository by running: `gradle uploadArchives`

I verified and indeed the library **.aar** is then available under the local maven repository.

The 2nd project is an Android app using *'android'* plugin for Gradle, which references the **maven dependency** of the library produced by the first project. Here is a snippet from *build.gradle*:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.example:cool-lib:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

> **NOTE: The two projects are completely separated from another. Meaning that,
>   they are NOT subprojects of the same root project.**

When I try to build the 2nd project by running: `gradle assemble`

I get the following error:

```
Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:r18.
Required by:
    com.example:app-project:unspecified > com.example:cool-lib:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I checked the **.pom** file of *cool-lib*, under my local maven repo folder and I saw that it has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>18.0.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, Gradle is trying to get the *support library-v4 **r18*** for the *lib-project* from maven central repository instead of getting it from *Android Support Repository*. It fails since the latest version in Maven Central of the *support-library-v4* is **r7**.

Is there a way to force Gradle to strictly fetch the *support-library-v4 **r18*** from *Android Support Repository* also for external Android libraries which are referenced from Maven Central?

Comment: I am also seeing the issue when using two libraries, one of which requires the other one. Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: I had the same error when my ANDROID_HOME environment variable was pointing to an old version of the SDK

Answer (score 38):

You need to install `Android Support Repository` from SDK manager. After that Gradle will be able to resolve support libraries from `${SDK_HOME}\extras\android\m2repository\`.

Comment: I had to do this after upgrading the SDK (following Android L release)

Comment: As written in the question: `The support library is fetched from Android Support Repository installed via Android SDK Manager as explained here`, implying that I already had it installed. This issue seemed to disappear by its own somehow, possibly due to the new Gradle build system becoming more mature.

Comment: Is there a way to install the support repository from the command line?

Comment: @martinkunev, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/23436564/750510

Answer (score 6):

make sure you have your local.properties file in main project folder and sdk.dir variable is pointing to Android SDK. (tested on mac)

Comment: I have ANDROID_HOME environment variable set for that purpose, I think it has the same affect according to my understanding...

Comment: I might be wrong but it depends where ANDROID_HOME is set. Is it set in .bashrc or .bash_profile? If so it is visible only in terminal but not from desktop. e.g. for gnome it will be somewhere else.

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` serves the same purpose as settings `sdk.dir`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Android Support Repository as madhead says. But in my case it was absent. You should go to the Tools->Manage Add-on Sites... and check all "Google Inc." sites. Then Android Support Repository will appear in the packages list, and you can install it.

Answer (score 2):

refer to: https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer

to download exactly support library