# Downloading the Android support library from command line

Tags: android-support-library, android-sdk-tools

How do you download the Android support library via the command line?

For example:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter "android-19"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```

Comment: This no longer works, the name of the extra is now `extra-android-m2repository`. 


`echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"`

Comment: thank you for the above comment, I was searching long and hard for this information

Answer (score 9):

`android` command is deprecated now

You can use `sdkmanager` instead like so:

```
sdkmanager --install "extras;android;m2repository"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
```

worked for me.
I ran in to the error: Warning: File /var/root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

so I had to create that file before running the above command.

```
touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

The *sdkmanager* should be your go to. Otherwise, there is another way which is what *sdkmanager* will do automatically. So, there are dangers to this, one typo and the whole thing will not work. Go to [Google Sources](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F) repository and choose either support or m2repository and download by clicking the tgz/archive link under the breadcrumbs.

Or use;

```
wget https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+archive/master/sdk/extras/android.tar.gz
```

The second option downloads a bigger file size (and two versions of the support library but neither is the newer [androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) referenced on the official Android development page). But, both will give you a zipped archive with the Android support library. Go to your  directory and create the extras directory. Use "extras/android" as a file path and unzip (use tar xvfj) your archive into it;

```
unzip <archive file>
mv -R <unzipped directory> <Android SDK home>/extras/android/
mv -R <unzipped and moved directory> <support>
```

Or

```
tar xvjf <archive file>
mv -R <unzipped directory> <Android SDK home>/extras/android/
mv -R <unzipped and moved directory> <support>
```

You should now have the Android support library installed in your SDK package.

[Further support in use](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/extras/support-library.html).