# Android support library v4 - 18.0.0 vs r18

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to build an Android project (via Maven) which depends on the Android Support Library V4 but specifies the version to be r18 and not 18.0.0.

My maven repo (.m2/repository) seem to be configured as 18.0.0 so i'm obviously getting a ton of file not found errors.

I have seen a colleagues computer is configured correctly. i.e. It contains directories r18 etc.

What is the difference and how do I setup my computer to be the same? Is one the new way of doing things? i.e. Did Google change the naming at some point?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the maven repo of Android Support Library v4 and in that I am not able to find the library with r18. Please check that out - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/support-v4

Comment: Support version 18 was released quite long time ago. At that time maven repository for android support libraries didn't exist and we have to use https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer. I don't remember all details but might be that setup of you project is dependent on these tooling

Comment: @EugenMartynov Sounds right. When was the maven repo for support libraries released?

Comment: Can you confirm if the r18 notation is obsolete or the new correct way please?

Comment: Take a look to most voted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380337/android-support-library-setup-with-maven. It will give you answers for all your questions I think. As for me you better to migrate to gradle. It will be painful at the start but it is correct and supported way of building android apps now. Until bazel version 2. But it is another story :)

Comment: You need to install Android Support Repository from SDK manager. After that Gradle will be able to resolve support libraries from ${SDK_HOME}\extras\android\m2repository\. check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559660/android-gradle-build-fails-could-not-find-com-google-androidsupport-v4r18

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Please read question. I am using Maven.

Comment: @EugenMartynov I had seen that thank you. But I am still confused what exactly is the r18 notation about? Project is currently configured for r18 and builds on other machines. I need to know if that is new or old way because if it is old I will change the project POM files to build with the new way. But need to justify to other team members.

Comment: There was no old way. I think creator of maven deployer decided to version support libraries with **r<major version>**. But I can not say for sure