# Visual Studio 2015 ADAL for Cordova plugin causes error: The command “platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat” exited with code 1

Tags: cordova, azure, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using VS2015 with VS Tools for Apache Cordova version 14.0.60202.6 and am getting to following error when adding the ADAL for Cordova plugin.  *It does not seem to matter whether I target a device or the Ripple emulator.*

[image]

**Steps to recreate the issue:**

1. File > New > Project (Ctrl+Shift+N)
2. Choose "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" template with default name "BlankCordovaApp1"
3. Once loaded, double click config.xml and choose Plugins tab
4. In the Core menu, choose the plugin **ADAL for Cordova** and click Add
5. Open the plugins folder to confirm *cordova-plugin-ms-adal* folder was added.  **note* The plugin ADAL for Cordova plugin also adds *cordova-plugin-whitelist*
6. Ctrl+Shift+B to build the app and you get the error below:

Stackoverflow articles suggest updating the Environment Variables but these are set correctly:
[image]

Here is my VS 2015 version and setup:
[image]

The biggest kicker in the pants is that this plugin in VS2013 works fine without any issues.

Please help!  Let me know if I can provide any additional info about my environment.

**SOLVED: by @SergeiGrebnov's comment below**

Comment: Hi Arthur, I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio. I tried to repro this but wasn't able to. Could you post the entire build log so we can investigate?

Comment: @MichaelBraude thanks for your help.  Uploaded the build log here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BHT1TW_KFXziQwbx5wTBoWBHHEZF_sr8W1nilMKXytY/edit

Comment: Thanks. I we'll take a look at this asap.

Comment: Another idea is to install `Android Support Repository` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20815578/255654

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is Android dev environment configuration issue, try installing `Android Support Repository` from `Android SDK` manager.